# make apache to read just one php file

Tags: linux, laravel, apache, dns, centos

I have a server.php file in my Laravel project . in my computer I can command PHP -S localhost:8000 server.php so if I make an HTTP request to localhost:8000 it goes and read server.php file .or if I type this URL: localhost:8000/anything/anything it goes to read server.php file. but in my Linux server
if I type domain/anything/anything it goes to var/www/anything/anything and read index.php at there. but I want to read just server.php and pass those anything/anything to server.php file and does not count them as directory.what is the apache config to do this job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use htaccess rewrite rules

```
RewriteRule ^anything/anything$ /server.php [L]
```

I suppose in your case you don't want it to match the exact string (anything/anything) so this might be the solution you're looking for:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /server.php?path=$1 [L]
```

So what the rule above will do is it will check everything that's entered after the url and pass it as GET (path variable) to server.php

Comment: thanks.i read rewrite rule usage and write it in my htaccess file .it works.

Comment: @sina-sharifi glad to have helped :)